# How to change js and css order in xml file? i want add js and css in footer or last in header.?

Tags: javascript, css

How to change js and css order in xml file? i want add js and css in footer or last in header.?

I want to change js order in product view page?

```
 <reference name="head">

    <action method="addItem">

            <type>skin_js</type>

            <name>js/jquery.js</name>

        </action>

        <action method="addItem">

            <type>skin_js</type>

            <name>js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js</name>

        </action>
```

i want to chanage order of this js this js added last or footer can any idea of to change order to js

Comment: i want add js in footer and last of all js?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add the js files at the end of page (just before body) in magento (not with the default functionality).

However you can change the order of the js files being loaded.

> 

```
<action method="addItem">

        <type>skin_js</type>

        <name>js/jquery.js</name>

    </action>

    <action method="addItem">

        <type>skin_js</type>

        <name>js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js</name>

    </action>
```

Will load jquery first then cloud-zoom, and

> 

```
 <action method="addItem">

        <type>skin_js</type>

        <name>js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js</name>

    </action>
  <action method="addItem">

        <type>skin_js</type>

        <name>js/jquery.js</name>

    </action>
```

Will load cloud-zoom first and then jquery.